# Is there a better way to put videos into the ipad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, video

I have many videos on my computer that I want to put in my iPad. When I use iTunes, I have to manually click one video by one video to input the video into the iPad. Is there a way I can multiselect or highlight/drag and drop into the iPad? It's taking up a lot of time just to tick and untick (remove) them from the iPad. (I can't sync all because I have more than 16gb of videos and it cant fit my iPad).

I've tried to google for ways to multi tick them, cntl + A doesn't work.

Am I doing it wrong?

[image: Manually ticking one by one]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created separate playlists for my devices (one for music and one for video). I just sync those playlists instead of manually maintaining the Sync Movies list. This is much easier since you can use the deeper integration of playlists in iTunes to manage the contents. (drag/drop, popup menu, ... etc).